# WP Job Manager - Show number of all search results found

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin "WP Job Manager" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) and I'd like to show a number of all search results.

At the moment I use jQuery to do that but it only counts the number of results that are displayed currently on the page:

```
$(".job_listing").length;
```

How to get the total number of found jobs?

Comment: You'll have to edit the PHP template that displays the job listings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet in your javascript:

```
$('div.job_listings').on('updated_results', (function(_this) {
    return function(event, results) {
        alert( results.found );
    };
})(this));
```

Essentially we're hooking into the 'updated_results' js event triggered in the WP Job Manager plugin at line 154 in `ajax-filters.js`.

You'll need to edit this js a bit. I'm not sure precisely what you want to do with the value so I've just alerted it to the screen.

Then in your theme `functions.php` or custom plugin add this code. Here we're hooking into the 'job_manager_get_listings_result' filter on line 205 of `class-wp-job-manager-ajax.php`. We're creating the 'found' parameter from the WP_Query object that WP Job Manager creates.

```
function result_add_jobs_total_count($result, $jobs){
    $result[ 'found' ] = $jobs->found_posts == 0 ? 0 : $jobs->found_posts;
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings_result', 'result_add_jobs_total_count', 10, 2 );
```

I took these snippets from the Listify theme at http://themeforest.net/item/listify-wordpress-directory-theme/9602611 and modified them a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but unfortunately this doesn't work for me, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'found' of undefined
(anonymous function) @ main.js:262
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3

It's a great find that it's used in the Listify theme but I think the number of results is just a number of displayed listings on the page as there's no pagination on the search results page.

Comment: No, Listify does use pagination and the number it displays is a total count. I may have got something wrong, give me a few minutes to check

Comment: @Mike I was missing some necessary php code. This works in default 2015 theme.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately this still isn't working for me but I've found another way to make it work thank's to your php code:) I'll post the solution a bit later on:]

Comment: No worries, glad to help. :)